# How to convert ps to same-looking pdf file?

Tags: pdf, converters, postscript

I have a `ps` file consisting of several pages, with the following entry for the bounding box:

```
%%PageBoundingBox: 36 36 7164 2124
```

When viewing this file with `okular` it looks ok. After the conversion to a pdf as follows

```
ps2pdf graph.ps
```

a `pdf` is created, but each page shows only a magnification for each of the `ps` file. For the conversion I also tried options like

```
-sPAPERSIZE=letter 
-dEPSCrop
```

with no visible effect. My question: How can I convert my `ps` file into a `pdf` file in such a way, that when viewed with `okular` the result looks identical?

Comment: There is a lot of ambiguity here. Postscript is a vector format, so scaling is by design flexible, and there is no "right" size. Also Okular is merely a PDF reader and that the right solution will work on PDFs being viewed in Acrobat or Chrome. Also, what do you mean "shows a magnification?" ps2pdf is a rich interpreter with lots of conversion options, as show here: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/doc/AFPL/6.50/Ps2pdf.htm but tell us more before we can figure this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the desired width and hight must be specified for the conversion, in this case the command would be

```
ps2pdf -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=7128  -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=2088  isearch.ps
```

as `7128` is the width and `2088` is the height of the bounding box for the given example.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Windows` (thus `gswin32c.exe`), you can use the following in the cmd prompt:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.18\bin\gswin32c.exe" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o TheFinalOutput.pdf YourFileToConvert.ps
```